# Design for determining file extension from header data in files

Tags: java, arraylist, nodes

I have an issue I have been trying to wrap my head around for two days now and haven't found anything online (or on here), so I thought I would post this question and see what kind of feedback I get. I have been coding a small program in my spare time that scans a directory of files (that have had their file extensions removed) and reads the file headers of each one in order to figure out the file extensions of each file. Up until now I have utilized a series of if/else if statements to satisfy the "pattern matching" function of my program....

```
private String fileHeaderCheck()
{
    /* ----- PNG File Type Verification ----- */
    if (headerCheck.buffer[0] == 0x89 && headerCheck.buffer[1] == 0x50 && headerCheck.buffer[2] == 0x4E && headerCheck.buffer[3] == 0x47
        && headerCheck.buffer[4] == 0xD && headerCheck.buffer[5] == 0xA && headerCheck.buffer[6] == 0x1A && headerCheck.buffer[7] == 0xA)
    {
        return ".png";
    }

    /* ----- JPG File Type Verification ----- */
    else if (headerCheck.buffer[0] == 0xFF && headerCheck.buffer[1] == 0xD8 && headerCheck.buffer[2] == 0xFF && headerCheck.buffer[3] == 0xE0)
    {
        return ".jpg";
    }

    // And so on and so on through the whole list of file types I am checking for

    else
        return "unknown";           
}
```

headerCheck is a Buffer object that contains a byte[] holding the data read in from  the first 512 bytes of the file. I am incorporating 25-30 different file types in this pattern matching process, so you can see the function will quickly become large and ugly. What I would like to do is use an ArrayList of Node objects that each contain: 1. a byte[] of a specific file type's header info, and 2. a String representing the file's extension type,
and then just iterate through the array comparing the Node byte[] with the headerCheck.buffer[], and whatever element matches I will append it's fileType to the end of the file that I read in the headerCheck.buffer[] from. My Node class is set up this way....

```
class Node  //if this is the "png" Node 
{
    byte[] metadata;
    String fileType;

    Node()
    {
        this.metadata = new byte[]{0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0xD, 0xA, 0x1A, 0xA};
        this.fileType = ".png";
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to initialize the ArrayList. Would I have to create/instantiate 25-30 separate node classes with the preconfigured data just to initialize the ArrayList and then add() them to it? That seems worse than all the if/else if statements or a switch...Second question is, once I have my ArrayList instantiated with all the Node objects, I am having trouble visualizing how to iterate through it's byte[] in order to compare it to the headerCheck.buffer[]. I am pushing the boundaries of my knowledge so for these questions I have no code because I don't know where to begin coding this stuff. I am thinking double-nested for loops but I haven't gotten that far yet because I haven't figured out an efficient way to initialize the ArrayList. I have even looked into some design patterns as a possible remedy, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated...Thanks

The Iteration Method (something along these lines):

```
boolean match;

for (int x = 0; x < pattens.get(metadata).size(); x++)
{
    if (headerCheck.buffer[x] != patterns.get(metadata[x])
    {
        match = false;
        return;
    }   
    else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very complicated approach that results in code that is difficult to maintain. If you are okay with revamping your whole design, I would like to propose an alternate approach as follows :

**Create an interface named** `FileExtension` :

```
interface FileExtension {
    public String getExtension(byte[] buffer);
}
```

**Create classes that contain the logic for determining the file extensions :**

```
class PNGExtension implements FileExtension {

    @Override
    public String getExtension(byte[] buffer) {
        /* ----- PNG File Type Verification ----- */
        String fileType = null;
        if (buffer[0] == 0x89 && buffer[1] == 0x50 && buffer[2] == 0x4E && buffer[3] == 0x47 && buffer[4] == 0xD && buffer[5] == 0xA
                && buffer[6] == 0x1A && buffer[7] == 0xA) {
            fileType = ".png";
        }

        return fileType;
    }

}

class JPGExtension implements FileExtension {

    @Override
    public String getExtension(byte[] buffer) {
        /* ----- JPG File Type Verification ----- */
        String fileType = null;
        if (buffer[0] == 0xFF && buffer[1] == 0xD8 && buffer[2] == 0xFF && buffer[3] == 0xE0) {
            fileType = ".jpg";
        }

        return fileType;
    }

}
```

**Create a composite concrete class that will finally be used for getting the file extension based on the first 512 bytes** :

```
class CompositeFileExtension implements FileExtension {

    private List<FileExtension> fileExtensions;

    public CompositeFileExtension() {
        //in the real world, this list can be populated through an IoC container
        fileExtensions = new ArrayList<FileExtension>();
        fileExtensions.add(new PNGExtension());
        fileExtensions.add(new JPGExtension());

    }

    @Override
    public String getExtension(byte[] buffer) {
        String fileExtension = null;
        for(FileExtension extension : fileExtensions) {
            if((fileExtension=extension.getExtension(buffer))!=null) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return fileExtension;
    }
}
```

Finally, all the pieces of code put together will work as follows :

```
public class FileMapperDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * 1. For each file in directory
         *    2. Read first 512 bytes into buffer array
         *       3. Create a new CompositeFileExtension object and pass it the buffer
         * 
         */

                     CompositeFileExtension fileExtensions = new CompositeFileExtension();

                     //4. get the file extension 
                     String fileExtension = fileExtensions.getExtension(buffer);

    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you only have to add new `FileExtension` objects to the `ArrayList` whenever a new type of file extension needs to be deduced from the buffer. You don't need to create two similar `byte` arrays (You create two byte arrays in your example.One for the first 512 bytes read from the array and the other for comparing with this array)

Comment: I was considering something like this when I was researching some design pattern books, but just didn't put the pieces together as clearly as you have laid them out.. I actually have another part of the program that uses a design similar to what you have outlined, but perhaps it is because I am doing so much at once that my brain is overloaded. I will refactor and revamp my code accordingly. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Misterblue01 That's exactly the reason why I spent my free time providing you the entire code. It takes some practice to visualize the components and how they wire together. I am sure you understand the concepts but just needed a push in the right direction. That being said, if you feel that this approach is better, don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your node class to something like this :

```
class FilePattern {
    byte[] metadata ;
    String extension ;

    public FilePattern(byte[] m, String ext) {
        this.metadata = m ;
        this.extension = ext ;
    }

    /* add the getters here */
}
```

Now, you can initialize the ArrayList while adding elements to it i.e.

```
ArrayList<FilePattern> patterns = new ArrayList<FilePattern>();
patterns.add(new FilePattern(new byte[]{ ... }, "extension"));
.... // for other patterns.
```

Next, loop through the elements of `patterns`, extract the metadata bytes and match with the bytes read from file and determine file type.

**Edit**: For looping, you can do something like this :

```
for(FilePattern f : patterns)
    if(Arrays.equals(f.getMetadata(), headerCheck.buffer))
        System.out.println("Found file with extension : ", f.getExtension());
```

Comment: That makes sense, and even if I use 25-30 add() function calls, I still cut down on the if/else statements in the pattern matching function. So would this be something similar how I should iterate through it?